# Error when showing data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating an app to show student data from a management panel to a  teacher panel. I created the database class to insert the data in the management panel:

```
package com.example.mytryapp;    
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "teacher";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "teacher_table";    

    private static final String NAME = "teacher_name";
    private static final String FATHER_NAME = "father_name";
    private static final String MOTHER_NAME = "mother_name";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String E_MAIL = "e_mail";
    private static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
    private static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";  

    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Context ctx;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "DATABASE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        data=db;
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    //+ ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                    + CONTACT + " TEXT,"
                    + E_MAIL + " TEXT,"
                    + SUBJECT + " TEXT,"
                    + EMP_ID + " TEXT"
                    + ");");             
          Log.d("database operation", "table created");         
    }       
     public void open() throws SQLException
     {
         DatabaseHelper db1 = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
            data = db1.getWritableDatabase();
     }    
     public void close()
     {
         data.close();
     }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXCEPTION EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);           
    }       
    public void onInsert(DatabaseHelper db,String name,String f_name, String m_name,String address,String contact,String e_mail,String subject,String emp_id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sql= db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("teacher_name",name);
        cv.put("father_name", f_name);
        cv.put("mother_name", m_name);
        cv.put("address", address);
        cv.put("contact", contact);
        cv.put("e_mail", e_mail);
        cv.put("subject", subject);
        cv.put("emp_id", emp_id);

        sql.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "ONE ROW INSERTED.....");
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseHelper dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={NAME,FATHER_NAME,MOTHER_NAME,ADDRESS,CONTACT,E_MAIL,SUBJECT,EMP_ID};
        Cursor CR=SQ.query(TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (CR != null) {
            CR.moveToFirst();
        }
        return CR;

    }

}
```

and activity is defined as:

```
package com.example.mytryapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManageStudent extends Activity{

    EditText ROLLNO,STUD_NAME,FATHERNAME,MOTHERNAME,BRANCH,ADDR,CONTACT,EMAIL;
    String rollno,stud_name,fathername,mothername,branch,addr,contact,email;
    Button btn_save;
    Context ctxx=this;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
    ab.setSubtitle("Be Here");
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    setContentView(com.example.mytryapp.R.layout.manage_student);   

    ROLLNO=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_rollno);
    STUD_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_name);
    FATHERNAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_fathername);
    MOTHERNAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_mothername);
    BRANCH=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_branch);
    ADDR=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_addrs);
    CONTACT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_contact);
    EMAIL=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_email);

    btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stud_save);

    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rollno=ROLLNO.getText().toString();
            stud_name=STUD_NAME.getText().toString();
            fathername=FATHERNAME.getText().toString();
            mothername=MOTHERNAME.getText().toString();
            branch=BRANCH.getText().toString();
            addr=ADDR.getText().toString();
            contact=CONTACT.getText().toString();
            email=EMAIL.getText().toString();  

            DataHelperStudent DB=new DataHelperStudent(ctxx);
            DB.open();                          
            DB.onInsertStudent(DB, rollno, stud_name, fathername, mothername, branch, addr, contact, email);                    
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "insertion sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          

        }
    });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater1 = getMenuInflater();
        inflater1.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
                 builder.setMessage("Do you want to logout ?")  
                 .setCancelable(false)  
                 .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                           
                         Intent std_time=new Intent(ManageStudent.this,ChoosePanel.class);
                        startActivity(new Intent(ManageStudent.this,ChoosePanel.class));
                     }  
                 })  
                 .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  

                     dialog.cancel();  
                  }  
                 });  


             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  

             alert.setTitle("LOGOUT");  
             alert.show();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:

                this.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
}
```

and this code is working properly.

I created another database class for the teacher panel to show the data of student:

```
package com.example.mytryapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataHelperStudent extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "teacher";

    //table
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_STUDENT="student_table";

    //private static final String ID="id";
    private static final String ROLL_NO = "roll_no";
    private static final String STUDENT_NAME = "student_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_FATHER_NAME = "student_father_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME = "student_mother_name";
    private static final String STUDENT_ADDRESS = "student_address";
    private static final String STUDENT_CONTACT = "student_contact";
    private static final String STUDENT_E_MAIL = "student_e_mail";
    private static final String STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH = "student_branch_batch";

    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Context ctx;

    public DataHelperStudent(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "DATABASE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        data=db;
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_STUDENT + " ("
                //+ ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + ROLL_NO + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + STUDENT_CONTACT + " TEXT,"
                    + STUDENT_E_MAIL + " TEXT"
                + ");");
          Log.d("database operation", "table created");

    }

    public void open() throws SQLException
     {
         DataHelperStudent db1 = new DataHelperStudent(ctx);
            data = db1.getWritableDatabase();
     }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXCEPTION EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public  void onInsertStudent(DataHelperStudent db,String roll_no,String name, String f_name,String m_name,String branch,String address,String contact,String e_mail)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sql= db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("roll_no",roll_no);
        cv.put("student_name", name);
        cv.put("student_father_name", f_name);
        cv.put("student_mother_name", m_name);
        cv.put("student_branch_batch", branch);
        cv.put("student_address", address);
        cv.put("student_contact", contact);
        cv.put("student_e_mail", e_mail);

        sql.insert(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, null, cv);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "ONE ROW INSERTED.....");
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(DataHelperStudent dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={ROLL_NO, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_FATHER_NAME, STUDENT_MOTHER_NAME, STUDENT_BRANCH_BATCH, STUDENT_ADDRESS, STUDENT_CONTACT, STUDENT_E_MAIL};
        Cursor CR=SQ.query(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (CR != null) {
            CR.moveToFirst();
        }
        return CR;

    }
    public Cursor getRollNo(DataHelperStudent dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sq=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={ROLL_NO};
        Cursor cr=sq.query(TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, coloumns, null, null,null,null,null);
        if (cr != null) {
            cr.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cr;
    }

}
```

and the two activities of teacher panel are one for get the `rollno` and the second for showing the data of that student in this way:

```
package com.example.mytryapp;

import com.example.mytryapp.R;    
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;    
public class TeacherGetStudentDetail extends Activity{      
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    EditText ROLLNO,NAME,FATHERNAME,MOTHERNAME,BRANCH,ADDRESS,CONTACT,EMAIL;
    String rollno,name,fathername,mothername,branch,address,contact,email;
    Button btn_save,btn_edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar ab=getActionBar();
          ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.teach_student);

        ROLLNO=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_roll);
        NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_student_name);
        FATHERNAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_father);
        MOTHERNAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_mother);
        BRANCH=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_branch);
        ADDRESS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_addrs);
        CONTACT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_contact);
        EMAIL=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_stud_email);           

        DataHelperStudent DB= new DataHelperStudent(TeacherGetStudentDetail.this);
        DB.open();
        Cursor CR = DB.getInformation(DB);

        if (CR.moveToFirst()) {
         do {   
             int nameFieldColumnIndex = CR.getColumnIndex("roll_no");
            rollno= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);

            int nameFieldColumnIndex1 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_name");
            name=CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex1);

             int nameFieldColumnIndex2 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_father_name");
            fathername= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex2);

            int nameFieldColumnIndex3 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_mother_name");
            mothername= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex3);

            int nameFieldColumnIndex7 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_branch_batch");
             branch= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex7);   

            int nameFieldColumnIndex4 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_address");
           address= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex4);

            int nameFieldColumnIndex5 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_contact");
           contact= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex5);

          int nameFieldColumnIndex6 = CR.getColumnIndex("student_e_mail");
            email= CR.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex6);

            ROLLNO.setText(rollno);
          NAME.setText(name);
          FATHERNAME.setText(fathername);
          MOTHERNAME.setText(mothername);
          BRANCH.setText(branch);
          ADDRESS.setText(address);
          CONTACT.setText(contact);
          EMAIL.setText(email);       

         } while (CR.moveToNext());
      }

      if (CR != null && !CR.isClosed()) {
         CR.close();
      }
      if(DB!=null)
      {
          DB.close();
    }                
        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rollno=ROLLNO.getText().toString();
                name=NAME.getText().toString();
                fathername=FATHERNAME.getText().toString();
                mothername=MOTHERNAME.getText().toString();
                branch=BRANCH.getText().toString();
                address=ADDRESS.getText().toString();
                contact=CONTACT.getText().toString();
                email=EMAIL.getText().toString();                       
                DataHelperStudent DB=new DataHelperStudent(TeacherGetStudentDetail.this);
                DB.open();                              
                DB.onInsertStudent(DB, rollno, name, fathername, mothername, branch, address, contact, email);                      
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "insertion sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                              
            }
        });   
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater1 = getMenuInflater();
        inflater1.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:                   
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
                 builder.setMessage("Do you want to logout ?")  
                 .setCancelable(false)  
                 .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                               
                         Intent std_time=new Intent(TeacherGetStudentDetail.this,ChoosePanel.class);
                        startActivity(new Intent(TeacherGetStudentDetail.this,ChoosePanel.class));
                     }  
                 })  
                 .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();  
                  }  
                 });            
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();                 
             alert.setTitle("LOGOUT");  
             alert.show();
                return true;                    
            case android.R.id.home:                 
                this.finish();
                return true;                    
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
}
```

this code was working properly during the last day, but today it shows this error:

```
05-13 03:12:57.251: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 326K, 9% free 4629K/5072K, paused 72ms, total 86ms
05-13 03:12:57.421: D/DATABASE OPERATION(933): DATABASE CREATED
05-13 03:12:57.542: D/DATABASE OPERATION(933): DATABASE CREATED
05-13 03:12:57.542: E/SQLiteLog(933): (1) no such table: student_table
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933): Error inserting roll_no=8 student_address=ldh student_father_name=hardesh student_name=monika student_mother_name=raj student_branch_batch=cse student_contact=26395426 student_e_mail=er.manju
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO student_table(roll_no,student_address,student_father_name,student_name,student_mother_name,student_branch_batch,student_contact,student_e_mail) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at com.example.mytryapp.DataHelperStudent.onInsertStudent(DataHelperStudent.java:87)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at com.example.mytryapp.ManageStudent$1.onClick(ManageStudent.java:64)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-13 03:12:57.641: E/SQLiteDatabase(933):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 03:12:57.641: D/DATABASE OPERATION(933): ONE ROW INSERTED.....
05-13 03:12:57.761: D/dalvikvm(933): GREF has increased to 201
05-13 03:13:11.651: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:14.521: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:16.054: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:17.681: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:20.891: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:29.811: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:33.151: I/Choreographer(933): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:37.311: D/DATABASE OPERATION(933): DATABASE CREATED
05-13 03:13:37.321: E/SQLiteLog(933): (1) no such table: student_table
05-13 03:13:37.331: D/AndroidRuntime(933): Shutting down VM
05-13 03:13:37.331: W/dalvikvm(933): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student_table (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT roll_no FROM student_table
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.example.mytryapp.DataHelperStudent.getRollNo(DataHelperStudent.java:106)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.example.mytryapp.TeacherStudent$1.onClick(TeacherStudent.java:49)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-13 03:13:37.531: E/AndroidRuntime(933):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 03:13:37.681: D/dalvikvm(933): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 263K, 8% free 5068K/5452K, paused 71ms, total 84ms
05-13 03:13:39.791: I/Process(933): Sending signal. PID: 933 SIG: 9
05-13 03:13:42.901: D/dalvikvm(994): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 9% free 2849K/3120K, paused 46ms, total 50ms
05-13 03:13:43.091: D/dalvikvm(994): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 10% free 3134K/3452K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
05-13 03:13:43.561: I/Choreographer(994): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-13 03:13:43.631: D/gralloc_goldfish(994): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

please help me to fix this...

Comment: student_table doesn't exist. Why is `//+ ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "` commented out ?

Comment: because firstly i'm use it but then relies no need of it coz there is roll no field to fetch the data

Comment: now i am using another database name for student table and its work.... :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the code is working properly till the last day. You should uninstall the app from device and run it again. In case of database, sometimes this type of error happens.

Comment: i got where i do mistake actually now i am using another database name for datahelperstudent clas

Comment: OK. But you said that your code was working properly till the last day. Therefore I posted this answer.